# How do I redirect my blog posts to a subdomain?

Tags: migration, domain

I currently have my blog at `alexangas.com` and would like to move it to `www.alexangas.com`.

Is this as simple as changing the **WordPress Address** and **Site Address** in Settings? How can I ensure that users hitting `alexangas.com/someblogpost` are automatically redirected to `www.alexangas.com/someblogpost`?

Comment: To clarify: `www.alexangas.com` is a CNAME for `alexangas.com`, so this simple solution will indeed work. The redirection is handled by the [`redirect_canonical`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/canonical.php) function. In more complicated situations (where they are not on the same server), you need a more advanced setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I just did an experiment on my own site to verify that changing those settings will redirect between www and non-www as you specify.